# Inverse of atomic capturing group

Tags: python, regex

In a sequence, I would like to obtain the position of multiple characters, and then characters *and* and positions of the characters in-between these.

For example, in `ABZYZABZAYAYABCYZA`, I start by matching all multiples of `Y` and `Z` using the atomic capturing condition.

```
import regex as re 
seq = 'ABZYZABZAYAYABCYZA'
iter = re.finditer(r'Y|Z', seq)
dd = {}
for matchedobj in iter:
        dd[matchedobj.group()] = dd.get(matchedobj.group(),[]) + [matchedobj.start()]
```

which gives

```
{'Y': [3, 9, 11, 15], 'Z': [2, 4, 7, 16]}
```

Then I would like to match all the whole space in between consecutive `Y` or `Z`. In this case, the output matches should be

```
{'AB': [0, 5], 'A': [8, 10], 'ABC':[12]}
```

Trying with non-capturing conditions:

```
iter = re.findter(r'\w*?(?:(Y|Z))', seq)
```

and with look arounds:

```
iter = re.finditer(r'[^YZ]\w+?(?=Y|Z)|(?<=Y|Z)\w+?(?=Y|Z)|(?<=Y|Z)\w+', seq)
```

both do not work properly.

Comment: Use `re.split(r'[YZ]+', text)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although `re.split` works well, it does not give me information about the positions which I'm after.

Comment: Then please update the question to add the expected behavior details. Right now, you say *my matches should be `AB` `AB` `A` `A` `ABC` and `A`.* - no mentioning of indices.

Comment: Note you are saving the matches to a *dictionary*, but you expect keys with the same names - that means, only the last one will be saved. You need a *list* (maybe of tuples), not a *dictionary*.

Comment: Try `for matchedobj in re.finditer(r'[^YZ]+', seq):
        dd.append((matchedobj.group(), matchedobj.start()))
`

Comment: Of course.. Thanks again @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is `X|Y` that matches a single character, `X` or `Y`. To reverse it, you may use `[^XY]` and to match any 1+ chars like that, all you need is to append the `+` quantifier.

Now, you are saving the matches to a *dictionary*, but you expect keys with the same names. That means, only the last value for each identical key will be saved. You need a list of tuples, not a dictionary.

Use

```
for matchedobj in re.finditer(r'[^YZ]+', seq): 
    dd.append((matchedobj.group(), matchedobj.start()))
```

Output; `[('AB', 0), ('AB', 5), ('A', 8), ('A', 10), ('ABC', 12), ('A', 17)]`